# Create a skeleton class in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to create a skeleton(template) class in Eclipse? Whenever I want to create a class in a specific package, I want every class to have this same main method. Is there a way to do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("[" + currentThreadName + "] Main thread started");

    /*
     * do some stuff here
     */ 

    System.out.println("[" + currentThreadName + "] Main thread ends");

}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't have a oop purpose. I could have done it with aspects as well. Why I want this is let's say I am gonna prepare a training video and create 12 classes for that. Every class needs to have this same lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Eclipse code templates. These are configured in the Preferences in 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates'.

You could put this code in the 'Class body' template (in the 'Code' section).